# How can I do this C++ highshool problem efficently? (Caesar Cipher)

Tags: c++

caesar.in cotains on the first line a text (max 256 chars), on the second line a number that represents the modification of each letter (<100) and on the third the word "encrypt" or "decrypt".
I have to use the Caesar cipher to crypt or decrypt each letter depending on the number on the 2nd line and put it in dbftbs.out. My code works, but it's so inneficient. How can I make it more efficient.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
char s[257], crypt[8];
int key,i,l;
int main()
{
    ifstream fi("caesar.in");
    fi.get(s, 257);
    fi >> key;
    fi.get();
    fi.get(crypt, 8);
    l = strlen(s);
    if (crypt[0] == 'e')
        for (i = 0; i <= l - 1; i++) {
            if ((int(s[i]) >= 97) && (int(s[i]) <= 122))
                if ((s[i] + key) > 122)
                    s[i] = 97 + ((s[i] + key) - 123);
                else
                    s[i] = s[i] + key;
            else if ((int(s[i]) >= 65) && (int(s[i]) <= 90))
                if ((s[i] + key) > 90)
                    s[i] = 65 + ((s[i] + key) - 91);
                else
                    s[i] = s[i] + key;
        }
    else
        for (i = 0; i <= l - 1; i++) {
            if ((int(s[i]) >= 97) && (int(s[i]) <= 122))
                if ((s[i] - key) < 97)
                    s[i] = 123 - (97 - (s[i] - key));
                else
                    s[i] = s[i] - key;
            else if ((int(s[i]) >= 65) && int(s[i]) <= 90)
                if ((s[i] - key) < 65)
                    s[i] = 91 - (65 - (s[i] - key));
                else
                    s[i] = s[i] - key;
        }

    ofstream fo("dbftbs.out");
    fo << s;
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: better to use characters instead of magic numbers .. `'a'` instead of `97`, etc.

Comment: Why do you think your code is too slow?  How are you measuring?  Have you profiled to find the bottleneck?

Comment: I use a website for highschool problems. And for this problem I get 60/100. The time limit must be 0.1s and the memory used 64MB/8MB

Comment: Hint: A Caesar Cipher uses the remainder operator, `%` and an offset.  Search the internet for "C++ Caesar Cipher" for examples.

Comment: If character `isupper`, then encrypted character = (((character - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A';  Try it out.

Comment: can you help me for decryption too?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine any speed issues with your code.

Maybe the online judge was throwing bad input at your code and that was a part of the problem. Or, please set the speed optimization flags in your compiler.

---

The problem in this question are the potential overflows. So, we need to deal with that.

Then we need to understand what decryption means. If encryption will shift everthing one to the right, decryption will shift it back to left again.

- So, with "def" and key=1, the encrpyted string will be "efg".
- And decrpytion with key=1, will shift it to left again. Result: "def"

We can observe that we simply need to shift by -1, so the negative of the key.

So, basically encryption and decryption can be done with the same routine. We just need to invert the keys.

Let us look now at the overflow problematic. For the moment we will start with uppercase characters only. Characters have an associated code. For example, in ASCII, the letter 'A' is encoded with 65, 'B' with 66 and so on. Because we do not want to calculate with such number, we normalize them. We simply subtract 'A' from each character. Then

- 'A' - 'A' = 0
- 'B' - 'A' = 1
- 'C' - 'A' = 2
- 'D' - 'A' = 3

You see the pattern. If we want to encrypt now the letter 'C' with key 3, we can do the following.

'C' - 'A' + 3 = 5  Then we add again 'A' to get back the letter and we will get 5 + 'A' = 'F'

That is the whole magic.

But what to do with an overflow, beyond 'Z'. This can be handled by a simple modulo division.

Let us look at 'Z' + 1. We do 'Z' - 'A' = 25, then +1 = 26 and now modulo 26 = 0 then plus 'A' will be 'A'

And so on and so on. The resulting Formula is: (c-'A'+key)%26+'A'

Next, what with negative keys? This is also simple. Assume an 'A' and key=-1

Result will be a 'Z'. But this is the same as shifting 25 to the right. So, we can simply convert a negative key to a psoitive shift. The simple statement will be:

```
if (key < 0)  key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;
```

And then we can call our tranformation function with a simple Lambda. One function for encryption and decrytion. Just with an inverted key.

Please see below one (of many possible) C++ solution, that uses this scheme. And please note. The whole transformation, encryption and decryption, is done with only ONE `std::transform` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

const std::string inFileName{ "r:\\ceasar.in" };
const std::string outFileName{ "r:\\dbftbs.out" };

int main() {

    // Open the files and check, if they could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ inFileName }; inputStream) {
        if (std::ofstream outputStream{ outFileName }; outputStream) {

            // Here we store intermediate information from the source file
            std::string text{}, command{};
            int key{};

            // Now, read data from the input file
            if (std::getline(std::getline(inputStream, text) >> key >> std::ws, command)) {

                // We need to check, if we have a valid command
                bool validCommand{};

                if (command == "encrypt") {
                    validCommand = true;
                }
                else if (command == "decrypt") {
                    // Revert the key
                    key = -key;
                    validCommand = true;
                }
                else std::cerr << "\nError. Invalid command'" << command << "'\n\n";

                // If the command was valid
                if (validCommand) {
                    // Then do the transformation
                    // Handle negative keys
                    if (key < 0)  key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;
                    // Transform and write to file 
                    std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(outputStream), [&key](const char c) {
                        char r{ c }; if (std::isalpha(c)) { if (std::isupper(c)) r = (c - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A'; else r = (c - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a'; } return r; });
                }
            }
            else std::cerr << "\nError. Invalid data in input file\n";
        }
        else std::cerr << "\nError. Could not open input file '" << inFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError Could not open output file '" << outFileName << "'\n\n";
}
```

---

EDIT: Some extended information, if you work with ASCII character representation. Please have a look at any ASCII table. You will see that any uppercase and lowercase character differ by 32. Or, if you look in binary:

```
char  dez  bin           char  dez  bin
'A'   65   0100 0001     'a'   97   0110 0001 
'B'   66   0100 0010     'b'   98   0110 0010 
'C'   67   0100 0011     'b'   99   0110 0011 
 . . .
```

So, if you already know that a character is alpha, then teh only difference between upper- and lowercase is bit number 5. If we want to know, if `char`  is lowercase, we can get this by masking this bit. `c & 0b0010 0000` that is equal to `c & 32` or `c & 0x20`.

If we want to operater on either uppercase or lowercase characters, the we can mask the "case" away. With `c & 0b00011111` or `c & 31` or `c & 0x1F` we will get always equivalents for uppercase charcters, already normalized to start with one.

```
char  dez  bin        Masking         char  dez  bin         Masking
'A'   65   0100 0001  & 0x1b = 1      'a'   97   0110 0001   & 0x1b = 1
'B'   66   0100 0010  & 0x1b = 2      'b'   98   0110 0010   & 0x1b = 2
'C'   67   0100 0011  & 0x1b = 3      'b'   99   0110 0011   & 0x1b = 3
 . . .
```

So, if we use an alpha character, mask it, and subtract 1, then we get as a result 0..25 for any upper- or lowercase character.

---

Additionally, I would like tor repeat the key handling. Positive keys will encrypt a string, negative keys will decrypt a string. But, as said above, negative keys can be transormed into positive ones. Example:

```
Shifting by  -1  is same as shifting by  +25
Shifting by  -2  is same as shifting by  +24
Shifting by  -3  is same as shifting by  +23
Shifting by  -4  is same as shifting by  +22
```

So,it is very obvious that we can calculate an always positive key by: `26 + key`. For negative keys, this will give us the above offsets.

And for positve keys, we would have an overflow over 26, which we can elimiate by a modulo 26 division:

```
'A'-->  0 + 26 = 26    26 % 26 = 0 
'B'-->  1 + 26 = 27    27 % 26 = 1 
'C'-->  2 + 26 = 28    28 % 26 = 2 
'D'-->  3 + 26 = 29    29 % 26 = 3
```

--> `(c + key) % 26` will eliminate overflows and result in the correct new en/decryptd character.

And, if we combine this with the bove wisdom for negative keys, we can write: `((26+(key%26))%26)` which will work for all positive and negative keys.

Combining that with that masking, could give us the following program:

```
const char potentialLowerCaseIndicator = c & 0x20;
const char upperOrLower = c & 0x1F;
const char normalized = upperOrLower - 1;
const int withOffset =  normalized + ((26+(key%26))%26);
const int withOverflowCompensation = withOffset % 26;
const char newUpperCaseCharacter = (char)withOverflowCompensation + 'A';
const char result = newUpperCaseCharacter | (potentialLowerCaseIndicator );
```

Of course, all the above many statements can be converted into one Lambda:

```
auto conv=[&](char c){return std::isalpha(c)?(char)((((c&31)-1+((26+(key%26))%26))%26+65)|c&32):c;};

// And the transformation with:
std::transform(text.begin(),text.end(),std::ostream_iterator<char>(outputStream),conv);
```

---

An the whole, even more compacted program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

const std::string inFileName{ "r:\\ceasar.in" };
const std::string outFileName{ "r:\\dbftbs.out" };

int main() {

    // Open the files and check, if they could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputStream{ inFileName }; inputStream) {
        if (std::ofstream outputStream{ outFileName }; outputStream) {

            // Here we store intermediate information from the source file
            std::string text{}, command{};
            int key{};

            // Now, read data from the input file
            if (std::getline(std::getline(inputStream, text) >> key >> std::ws, command)) {

                // Lambda / Function for Ceasar encryption/decryption
                auto conv=[&](char c){return std::isalpha(c)?(char)((((c&31)-1+((26+(key%26))%26))%26+65)|c&32):c; };
                auto doJob=[&](bool r){if (r)key=-key;std::transform(text.begin(),text.end(),std::ostream_iterator<char>(outputStream),conv); };

                // Check parameter
                if (command == "encrypt")       doJob(false);
                else if (command == "decrypt")  doJob(true);
                else std::cerr << "\nError. Invalid command'" << command << "'\n\n";
            }
            else std::cerr << "\nError. Invalid data in input file\n";
        }
        else std::cerr << "\nError. Could not open input file '" << inFileName << "'\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError Could not open output file '" << outFileName << "'\n\n";
}
```

Please note, most of the program is file IO and error handling.